# df.max() not returning highest value in my data set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Complete Python newbie here. I have a small dataset and I want to return a row where a column in that row is the highest using pandas and `df.max()`.

Here is my data set:

```
Destination,     Score,Star Rating,Bags,City
---------------------------------------------------
Australia,       8,    4,          1,   Sydney
Papua New Guinea,7,    4,          2,   Port Moresby
Fiji,            9,    3,          2,   Suva
New Zealand,     8,    4,          1,   Wellington
Western Samoa,   6,    5,          2,   Apia
Tuvalu,          5,    4,          1,   Funafuti
French Polynesia,8,    3,          1,   Pape'ete
Tonga,           6,    2,          2,   Nuku'alofa
Christmas Island,7,    3,          2,   Flying Fish Cove
Cook Islands,    8,    4,          1,   Avarua District
Solomon Islands, 5,    3,          2,   Honiara
```

I am using the following to return the row for the highest in the `Score` column. This should be `Fiji` with a score of `9`.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.read_csv("Australasia.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(frame)
print("The highest scoring destination is: "+ str(df.loc[df["Score"].max()]))
```

For some reason this keeps returning the `Cook Islands`, which have a score of `8`.

```
The highest scoring destination is: 
Destination       Cook Islands
Score                        8
Star Rating                  4
Bags                         1
City           Avarua District
Name: 9, dtype: object
```

Can anyone help to advise as to why this is not returning the highest value in the score column, which is 9 and not 8?

I have used the exact reverse of this for a `df.min()` without issue and have no idea why max isn't working.

Comment: Because you are getting the index of the `max` value. Use `str(df['Score'].max())`, don't use `loc`

Comment: Also its cleaner to use f-strings here: `print(f"The highest scoring destination is: {df['Score'].max()}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.read_csv('Australia.csv')
max_score = frame['Score'].max()
print(f'Max score is {max_score}')
best_destinations = ','.join(frame[frame['Score'] == max_score]['Destination'].to_list())
print(f'Area(s) with max_score : {best_destinations}')
```

Output:

```
Max score is 9
Area(s) with max_score : Fiji
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. This works to bring back a single value for the highest score, but I need to be able to show all of the values from that row, or at the very least the destination and score.